# How can I display Google maps inside flash using javascript api v3?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-maps

I know there´s an api for flash but it has been deprecated, how can i display google maps inside flash using javascript api v3

Answer (score 0):

you can look to use an [iFrame](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe) and run your map in there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however it´s based on mxml and mx.core packages... is there any other solution? i´d rather keep it like an as3 pure project...

Answer (score 0):

You can use another Map API like MapQuets or Umap. Those api's have 
syntax similar to google API - it will be easy to migrate. Also I think there are no any tools to use "javascript api v3" in Flash, even with IFrame, but you can create some libs by yourself