# How can we get google map api key for flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps

How can we get google map api key for flex application?

I am using flex web application which display google maps, it is working fine in local host
but when i deploy in server,application gives error.

**

> Initialization failed: please check the API key, swf location, version
>   and network availability.

**
How can i resolve this problem, plez suggest me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The google maps flash api is deprecated, you should use the google maps v3 api which does not require an api key AFAIK. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405950/how-can-i-display-google-maps-inside-flash-using-javascript-api-v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, understand that the Flash Maps API is deprecated, and could be turned off in less than 2 years. So if you're doing development on a project that is going to stick around, you should use the JavaScript Maps API.

If this is an existing application and you moved domain or for some reason the key isn't working, here are the directions to request a key:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/intro#API_Key